# ngFor avanzado con Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directivas

¡Hola a todos! Tengo un ngFor en el HTML tal que así:

```html
<div *ngFor="let j of files">
 <div>
   <h3>{{j.titulo}}</h3>
   <p>{{j.parrafo}}</p>
 </div>
 <a href="{{j.archivo}}">Download</a>
</div>
```

Viene dado por el array de objetos "files" y con "j.year" imprimiría el año del archivo en cuestión.

El caso es que quiero separar los archivos por año, pero sólo quiero poner un título del año una vez y todos los archivos de ese año, y así sucesivamente.

```html
AÑO 1
 archivo 1
 archivo 2
AÑO 2
 archivo 3
 archivo 4
```

Entiendo la lógica en otros lenguajes, pero me veo muy limitado en el HTML con Angular. Probé con *ngFor="let j of file; let year=j.year" pero no funciona...

¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo tienes que crear un nuevo objeto y agrupar por año primero.

En tu componente haces esto

```
// Agrupas por año en un objeto, puedes usar un arreglo pero así es más rápido
const grouped = this.files.reduce((curr, file) => {
    if (!curr[file.year]) {
        // Si no has tenido ninguna entrada de ese año la agregas pero usando un arreglo
        curr[file.year] = [file];
    } else {
        // Si ya tienes ese año lo agregas al final del arreglo
        curr[file.year].push(file);
    }
    return curr;
}, {});

// Luego conviertes ese objeto en un arreglo que *ngFor puede iterar
this.groupedFiles = Object.keys(grouped).map(year => {
    return {
        year: year,
        files: grouped[year]
    };
});
```

Y modificas tu html para que tenga dos ciclos, uno por año y otro por fichero

```
<div *ngFor="let g of groupedFiles">
    <h2>{{g.year}}</h3>
    <div *ngFor="let j of g.files">
        <div>
            <h3>{{j.titulo}}</h3>
            <p>{{j.parrafo}}</p>
        </div>
        <a href="{{j.archivo}}">Download</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Con lodash y [`groupBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#groupBy) ese código puede simplificarse pero ya es decisión tuya si quieres hacerlo o no.

Comment: Gracias @devconcept ! Pensé que Angular tendría alguna forma más elegante en la que resolviera ésto sin tener que tirar de JavaScript, aunque es una opción que sirve cuando no se quiera/pueda modificar el back-end. Veremos si alguien tiene otra solución, si no, marco la tuya como la solución. ¡Gracias nuevamente!

Comment: @Xabi Si la hay pero realmente genera mucho trabajo y no siempre vale la pena. Puedes usar un custom [`Pipe`](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#custom-pipes) que te haga todo ese trabajo pero eso sólo vale si ese código se usa en muchos lugares diferentes y no quieres hacer una función helper para ello.

Comment: Genial @devconcept, voy a investigar cómo hacerlo con Pipes, ya que como dices, lo voy a usar mucho y quería hacerlo de una forma más optimizada. Gracias por la orientación, saludos.